# how to pass uploaded file name server side through delete option using fine Uploader

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, fine-uploader

Here the code I'm using:

```
deleteFile: {
   enabled: true,
   method: "POST",
   forceConfirm: true,
   params:{
      id: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery")
   },
   endpoint: '/FineUpload/Delete'
},
callbacks: {
   onDelete: function(id) {
      this.setDeleteFileParams({filename: this.getName(id)}, id)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very close! You should pass new delete file request parameters in an `onSubmitDelete` callback handler, instead of `onDelete`. So your callbacks option should look this:

```
callbacks: {
   onSubmitDelete: function(id) {
      this.setDeleteFileParams({filename: this.getName(id)}, id)
   }
}
```

I have updated the documentation for [`onDelete`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html#delete) and [`onSubmitDelete`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html#submitDelete) to steer others with this goal in the correct direction.